# Finding how many occurrences of two given numbers in the array

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    int c[] = {10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33 ,3}, num1, num2;
    int count = 0; 
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers : " ;
    cin  >> num1 >> num2;       
 }
```

How to complete code?

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Learn about C++ [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)s and use them (or use loops). Read some [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* site

Comment: As advised read some books, and try to understand `loops` and `if`

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code or output, unless your question is about graphics or colours. Post text as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Choice of container

Instead of using a *C-style array* as the *container* for your *collection* of `int`s:

```
int c[] = {10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33, 3};
```

I would recommend you to use either [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<int, 7> c{10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33, 3};
```

or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<int> c{10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33, 3};
```

---

#### Linear search

The collection doesn't need to be sorted, and the time running complexity for finding the occurrences of an element in the collection is O(n). The function template [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) can be used for this purpose:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::count

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c{10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33, 3};

    int num1, num2;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    // apply linear search
    auto count = std::count(c.begin(), c.end(), num1);
    count     += std::count(c.begin(), c.end(), num2);

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

---

#### Binary search

Finding the occurrences of an element in the collection can be achieved with a running time complexity of O(log n). However, the collection you apply binary search on **must be sorted** (yours it is not). It can be sorted in O(n log n) by means of [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) can be used for obtaining the range of all the occurrences of an element in the sorted collection by applying binary search on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>  // std::distance
#include <algorithm> // std::sort, std::equal_range

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c{10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33, 3};

    int num1, num2;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    // sort collection
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());

    // apply binary search
    auto itp = std::equal_range(c.begin(), c.end(), num1);
    auto count = std::distance(itp.first, itp.second);

    itp = std::equal_range(c.begin(), c.end(), num2);
    count += std::distance(itp.first, itp.second);

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

---

Which approach to use depends on the number of searches that you are going to perform on the collection.

- Linear search takes O(n).
- Binary search takes O(log n), but the collection must be sorted, and that takes O(n log n).

If you are going to perform *N* searches and *N* is much bigger than *n* (i.e., the number of elements in the collection), then it would be better to use binary search, otherwise the linear search.

For your particular case: *n* = 7 and *N* = 2. Therefore, better to stick to the linear search approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use searching algorithms for this problem.

There are two prevalent searching algorithms:

- Linear Search
- Binary Search

I have used Linear Search. Here is the solution:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int c[] = {10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33 ,3}, num1, num2;
        int count = 0; 
        int arr[] = {num1,num2};
        cout << "Enter 2 numbers : " ;
        cin  >> num1 >> num2;
        arr[0]=num1;
        arr[1]=num2;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==c[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<"The numbers has "<<count<<" matches with this array";
     }
```

Here I have created an array of the two numbers to be checked and then searched for it in the given array c.

Comment: Just wanted to say, that for using Binary search, you need to have the collection of elements sorted first. This would make sense in case you need to check the occurence of numbers in the collection more than once.

Answer (score 1):

First the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    int c[] = {10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33 ,3}, num1, num2;
    int count = 0; 
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers : " ;
    cin  >> num1 >> num2;
    auto q1 = std::count(std::begin(c), std::end(c), num1);
    auto q2 = std::count(std::begin(c), std::end(c), num2);
    cout << num1 << ": " << q1 << "\n" << num2 << ": " << " " << q2;
}
```

Explanation:

The algorithm library contains common algorithms you might want to use. Some of them use iterators for containers (beginning iterator and ending iterator, if you're not familiar with them you can think of them as pointers for now). count is an algorithm that counts occurrences of an item in a set.
To get iterators from you c-array you can use std::begin adn std::end. Other alternatives include using a vector or an std::array instead of a c-array. Example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    int c[] = {10, 12, 14, 32, 2, 33 ,3}, num1, num2;
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.assign(c, c + (sizeof(c)/sizeof(int)));
    std::array<int, 7> cpp;
    std::copy(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::begin(cpp));
    int count = 0; 
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers : " ;
    cin  >> num1 >> num2;
    //auto q1 = std::count(std::begin(c), std::end(c), num1);
    //auto q2 = std::count(std::begin(c), std::end(c), num2);
    //auto q1 = std::count(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), num1);
    //auto q2 = std::count(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), num2);
    auto q1 = std::count(std::begin(cpp), std::end(cpp), num1);
    auto q2 = std::count(std::begin(cpp), std::end(cpp), num2);
    cout << num1 << ": " << q1 << "\n" << num2 << ": " << " " << q2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include< iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    int Array = [] = { 1,33,43,75,96,44,55 };
    int size = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(int), i;
    cout << "Enter two numbers:\n";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (Arrar[i] % num1 == 0)  cout << endl << num1 << " is matched";

        if (Arrar[i] % num2 == 0)  cout << endl << num2 << " is matched";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please add an explanation for why your code solves the problem.